# Google Sheets - formula to sum per category

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77373415/2996797) I learned how to sum a column of amounts, converting them to a specific currency as well.

As a continuation to this question - each row has a "category" column, and these category values repeat themselves. In a new sheet I listed all category names (so each name appears only once), and I need to get the sum above split into these categories.

The [following sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_QB7Ykn1PYt6_vJPLY_7C0gN2mzomkY73qELobxv5y8/edit?usp=sharing) has "Sheet1" with general data (and formula), and "Sheet2" has data split into unique category names - I need help with this sheet to get the formula from the first sheet to work in this sheet.

(The sample has only a few rows, the real data has thousands of rows and categories, so I cannot just do individual formulas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in Cell A1 of Sheet2:

```
=query({
 Sheet1!A2:A,
 MAP(Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!C2:C,LAMBDA(val,cur,IFERROR(val*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&cur&"USD"),val)))
 },
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 
   label Col1 'category', sum(Col2) 'Sum'")
```

---

**LOGIC**

- `MAP(Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!C2:C,LAMBDA(val,cur,IFERROR(val*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&cur&"USD"),val)))`

  - returns the USD value of each currency value in each row.
- `query({Sheet1!A2:A,...`

  - a query is used to sum and group the results
  - Column 1 is the category value
  - Column 2 is the USD converted value
- `select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1`

  - Sum the USD value and group by the category
- `label Col1 'category', sum(Col2) 'Sum'`

  - Housekeeping for header labels

---

**RESULTS**

[image: snapshot]

---

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I'm stuck a bit as I have one more condition/criterion to check for in another column (i.e. "if the cell in column d is "X" then multiply by 2, otherise don't multiply). How can I incorporate this?

Comment: Off the top of my head (which means that there is probably a better way to do this)... use the Map/Lambda formula; recognize the extra column of data, then wrap an `IF` statement around the `IFERROR`. Something like this: `=MAP(B2:B,C2:C,D2:D,LAMBDA(val,cur,twoby,if(twoby="x",2*(IFERROR(val*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&cur&"USD"),val)),IFERROR(val*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&cur&"USD"),val))))`

Comment: Yes I finally did something similar to that, thanks so much.